# Why does integer++ not increment integer value?

Tags: c, operators, post-increment

Why does `num1++` not increment in the `printf()`?

```
int num1 = 1;
printf("num1=%d", num1++);
```

Why does this print `num1=1` instead of `num1=2`?

Comment: You *do* know the difference between prefix and suffix incrementing? I.e. the difference between e.g. `++num1` and `num1++`?

Comment: Num1++ is post increment. In next line after printf if num1 is used, it's value will be 2.

Comment: Go with `printf("num1=%d", ++num1);`

Comment: What made you think it doesn't increment it? The code you posted does not check the value of `num` after `++`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pre increment vs Post increment in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869020/pre-increment-vs-post-increment-in-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the expression

```
num1++
```

evaluates to `num1`.

---

You may want to do:

`++num1`

which evaluates to `num1 + 1`.

---

Note however that both expressions increment `num1` by one.

Evaluating `num1` in the next statement evalutes to the incremented value.

---

## In short

> In C, why doesn't num1++ increment in the printf()?

`num1++` does increment `num1` but it evaluates to `num1` and that evaluation is what you are passing to `printf()`.

Comment: Yes, but why? I mean, I know why, but if it was so obvious OP wouldn't have asked.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca because both operators are useful in different cases?

Comment: @Quentin not "why does it exist", why `n++` evaluates to `n` if I didn't know `++n` was different (or even existed). I was asking Neroku to better detail their answer.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca This might be me being stupid, but I don't see any other answer to that than "because C was designed that way"...

Comment: @Quentin I updated my last comment. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: I guess I'm not following. If you do num1++, it will increment. If you do it in printf, it will not. You are saying num1++ evaluates to num1. I don't know what that means since it increments the value but not when you do it in printf.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, for example, you can use `*p++` and `*++p`. It depends on when do you want to obtain the incremented value.

Comment: @4thSpace both `++` operators have the *side-effect* of incrementing their operand. But they also have a (*evaluate to a*) value, which is what you pass to `printf`. They differ in what their value is.

Comment: @Neroku, I know C, I'm not asking for myself. But as you see 4thSpace is still confused, what I'm saying is that your answer is not clear for someone who's new to these kind of things.

Comment: I understand now. A better answer would simply have been: with num1++, you'll see the updated result on the next line. With ++num1, you'll see the result on the current line.

Comment: And that answer would be wrong. C doesn't have a notion of "lines" in this meaning. It has a notion of "sequence points"..

Comment: @EugeneSh. I've never talked about "lines"

Comment: @Neroku Sorry for not prefixing, but I've commented to the chronologically previous comment of the OP

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca after *side effects* (either for `++num1` or `num1++`) are over it is guaranteed that `num1` evaluates to the incremented value. Which operator you choose depends on your intention.

Comment: Actually, another interesting question would be: ***when** does this increment take place?* Or *when is it guaranteed have been done?*

Answer (score 9):

The `++` **does** increment the operand ... but in its postfix form, it **evaluates** to the value **before** incrementing.

`++num1` instead would evaluate to the value **after** incrementing.

Answer (score 3):

It comes from the fact that the ++ is after the variable, this will solve your problem

```
printf("num1=%d", ++num1);
```

The way you did your variable will be incremented after printing out its content, so if you do another printf on this variable you should have the right value, by putting it in the prefix way, it will increment the variable before outputting it

Answer (score 3):

The postfix `++` operator evaluates to the **current** value of the operand, **then** it increments it.  If you call `printf` again with `num1` as the argument, you would see the effect of the increment.

From section 6.5.2.4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *2* The result of the postfix `++` operator is the value of the operand. As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that
>   is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it).

If you used the prefix `++` operator, i.e. `++num1`, the increment would be reflected in the output.

Answer (score 3):

Because having the ++ at the end of the variable causes the increment to happen after the operation. Adding the ++ before the variable will do the addition before the operation.

Comment: Short answers such as this one are generally better suited as comments.  You can support your response with a short code example.

Comment: This is literally the simplest and best understandable  answer under this post. If you're explaining simple things to a beginner programmer it's generally better to use everyday language and not phrases like postfix, prefix, evaluate, etc etc.