# Please explain the output of this piece of C code

Tags: c, arrays

I am not able to make sense of the first line inside the loop body.

How to interpret this statement:
        `printf("%d", i++[a]);`

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {

        int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

        for(int i=0; i<5; i+2){
            printf("%d", i++[a]);
            printf(",%d",i);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

***Output***

1,12,23,34,45,5

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<5; i+2)` i+2 is useless.

Comment: wow.. downvotes

Comment: @ishon19 But also *up* votes ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line

```
printf("%d", i++[a]);
```

prints the `i`th element of the `a` array and then subsequently increments `i`.

Remember, that `a[42]` and `42[a]` is the exact same thing in C++ (since "address + offset" is the same as "offset + address" under the hood).

This is the same thing written in a more conventional manner:

```
printf("%d", a[i++]);
```

Comment: Note: the increment of `i` can happen before or after the array element is accessed. In C (before C18, I don't know if the rules changed with the latest revision), there is no requirement for the order of operations in `i++[a]`.

Comment: @pmg I believe you are not correct. `i++` will use the current value of `i` before incrementing. `++i` would increment first and *then* use the value of `i`. I'm *fairly sure* this is well defined in the context of array indexing. And the answer by @Achal provides chapter and verse from the (C) standard (but this is (AFAIK) the same for C++).

Comment: Assuming `i == 0`, `i++[a]` ... will (possibly only pre-C18) do either one of a) `i=1;a[0];` or b) `a[0];i=1;`

Comment: @pmg I still disagree. Please point to the part of the C++ standard that supports your argument. I don't believe you can find one.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: [C11 sequence points (Annex C)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#C)

Comment: @JesperJuhl: [C11 6.5p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p3) "... Except as specified later, side effects and value computations of subexpressions are unsequenced."

Comment: @pmg if that reading applied to array indexing (which I believe it does not), then `a[i++]` would also be unsequenced, which I hope we can agree is not the case. And since `i++[a]` is quite literally *the exact same thing* as `a[i++]`, then it is also not unsequenced.

Comment: The compiler could conceivably even emit code that fetches the `a` element and increments the `i` variable at the same time, in parallel: hence **unsequenced** :)

Comment: @pmg then you should also downvote https://stackoverflow.com/a/16869073/5910058 - also, this language seems to contradict you "A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets [] is a sub scripted designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer, E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero)."

Comment: @JesperJuhl: your answer got my upvote, not downvote (and the answer you linked to here is wrong and got a downvote -- not that I'm on a crusade for the proper explanation of order of evaluation or anything).

Comment: @JesperJuhl: The *side effect* of incrementing `i` is unsequenced with respect to indexing into `a`.  `i++` will *evaluate* to the current value of `i`, and `++i` will evaluate to the current value of `i + 1`, but `i` won’t necessarily be updated immediately after evaluation; it’s only guaranteed to be updated by the next sequence point.

Comment: @JohnBode But as far as indexing into the array and accessing a value is concerned, we argree that everything is well defined? Right? Btw; I don't think sequence points are a thing in the most recent versions of the standard.. they are of course still there in some sense, but the language has changed.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Yeah, as long as we’re not doing something like `a[i++] = i` or `a[i] = ++i`, everything’s good.  `a[i++]` has the same result as `a[i]` and `a[++i]` has the same result as `a[i+1]` - it’s just that the update to `i` may happen before or after the array access.

Comment: @JohnBode Of course. But that's not what this question (or answer) is about.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
i++[a];
```

where `a` is an array is valid as `a[i]` and `i[a]` are same. In this particular case post increment `++` happens later i.e first `i[a]` executes and then `i` increments.

From the **C** Standard

**6.5.2.1** **Array subscripting**

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets `[]`
>   is a sub scripted designation of an element of an array object.  The
>   definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that  `E1[E2]` is
>   identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`.  Because of the conversion rules that
>   apply to the binary `+` operator, if `E1` is an **array object**
>   (equivalently, *a pointer to the initial element of an array object*)
>   and `E2` is an **integer**, `E1[E2]` designates the `E2-th` element of
>   `E1` (counting from zero).

Answer (score 1):

The loop section can be re-written in this form as they are exactly same.

We know that `a[1]` and `1[a]` are same things, second member of array.

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i+2){
    printf("%d", a[++i]);
    printf(",%d",i);
}
```

The  `printf("%d", a[++i]);` in turn can be interpret as

```
printf("%d", a[i]);
i++;
```

As a side note, `i+2` in third section of for loop is useless and can be removed.

```
for(int i=0; i<5;){
    printf("%d", a[++i]);
    printf(",%d",i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d", i++[a]);
```

***a[i] and i[a]*** are the same.