# How to explain the following JavaScript code? Why the for loop can stop automatically?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

How to explain the following JavaScript code? Why the for loop can stop automatically?

```
for (let i = 5; i--; ) {
  for (let j = 3; j--; ) {
    console.log(i, j);
  }
}
// 4 2
// 4 1
// 4 0
// 3 2
// 3 1
// 3 0
// 2 2
// 2 1
// 2 0
// 1 2
// 1 1
// 1 0
// 0 2
// 0 1
// 0 0

for (let i = 0; i--; ) {
  for (let j = 3; j--; ) {
    console.log(i, j);
  }
}
// No output

for (let i = false; i--; ) {
  for (let j = 3; j--; ) {
    console.log(i, j);
  }
}
// No output
```

It seems like when `i` is falsy, the for loop will automatically stop. I thought the for loop will stop only when `i--` is false.

Answer (score 1):

If `i` starts out as 0, `i--` will be falsey because post-increment takes the *current* value of the variable and decrements the variable. `i--` is 0 when `i` starts at 0:

```js
let i = 0;
console.log(i--);
```

The same sort of thing is happening with `for (let i = false; i--; ) {` - the fact that `i` starts out as `false` instead of `0` still makes it falsey:

```js
let i = false;
console.log(i--);
```

So no iterations occur.

Answer (score 0):

According to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_for.asp#:%7E:text=Definition%20and%20Usage,code%20a%20number%20of%20times) definition, `for` parameters are optional.

- The first one is executed before to initiate the loop.
- The second one is a condition, while this condition returns true, the for loop continues.
- The last one is executed ending every loop.

Now, let's check the examples:

```
for (let i = 5; i--; )
```

In this case, the first statement it's initializing `i` into 5. The second statement is evaluating if `i--` it's equals to true. And we have not a third statement.

The loop ends because `i` will be 0 and it's coerces to `false`, but why do it print 0? Well, this is because in a post-decrement the value of the variable is evaluated first and after proceeds with the decrement, (you can check an explanation of post-increment and pre-increment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869020/pre-increment-vs-post-increment-in-array#:%7E:text=Pre-incrementation%20means%20the%20variable,then%20the%20variable%20is%20altered.&text=That%20means%20increment%20the%20value,it%20to%20the%20variable%20i.))

Now, in the following examples

```
for (let i = 0; i--; )
for (let i = false; i--; )
```

the seconds statements will always return false, and this breaks the for loop. Remember that `false` will coerce to 0 when try `false--`