# C-Arithmetics and precedence

Tags: c, integer, calculation

I'm practicing to read C-code faster but I'm struggling to understand this portion:

```
int a = 7, b = 3, c = 2, d;

d = (b+c >a) || a > c ? a-- : a++;
```

When I enter this into my program and print out integer d, I get the result of 7. But I cannot really understand why. Can somebody please explain this to me?

Comment: In situations where you expect something different, you should always add what you expect and why. That helps a lot to provid specific help to a specifig problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning to `d` the value of either `a--` or `a++`. Both of these expressions have a value of `7` (the *original* value of `a`); the difference between the operators is what they do to their operand (`a`) *after* evaluating the expression: one then increments it and the other decrements it.

That is why they are called **post**-increment and **post**-decrement operators.

Maybe you are getting confused with the **pre**-increment and **pre**-decrement operators, which are `++a` and `--a`? (See also: [Pre increment vs Post increment in array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16869020/10871073) .)

As for the ternary operator (`x ? y : z`) and how to 'read' that, then you can take it as `if x then y else z;` so, if the result of the test (which has a logical OR, which means it will be true if *either* comparison is true) is true, then `d = a--`, otherwise `d = a++`. But, as mentioned already, both will give the same value to `d`, in this case (though they will have different effects on `a`). Note also that the ternary operator has a [lower precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than either the logical OR or the relational comparisons, so you can read as though everything between the `=` and the `?` is in (another set of) brackets.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I understand the portion with the increments but I'm struggling to understand the part before that. Shouldn't I also consider that logical OR operator? 

So if I insert the numbers, it is d = (3+2 >7) || 7 > 2 ? 7: 7;

So maybe my question is: in what order do I have to "read" this line of code?

Comment: @Phonzy See edit ... that may clarify things a bit more.

Comment: One reason we get so many repetitions of questions about `++` and `--` is students are taught incorrectly. “… what they do after the expression's value is assigned” is incorrect: C implementations may perform the increment or decrement before, during, or after the assignment. A correct statement is that the expression uses the value of the operand from before the increment or decrement, regardless of when the increment or decrement occurs. Every student that is taught incorrectly is another person who has to be corrected later.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Your precision is, as ever, appreciated. Hopefully, the edit I made improves the post.

Answer (score 1):

The expression is parsed as

```
d = ((b+c >a) || a > c) ? a-- : a++;
```

so `d` gets the result of either `a—` or `a++`, which is `7` in both cases.  The difference is what the value of `a` is after the expression is evaluated.

`||` forces left to right evaluation, so `b+c > a` is evaluated first.  Since `b+c` is `5`, the result of the expression is false (`0`), so `a > c` is evaluated.  The result of that expression is true (`1`), so the result of `(b+c > a) || a > c` is true (`1`), meaning we assign the result of `a—` to `d`.  Thus `d` will be `7` and `a` will be `6`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how operator precedence works in C

Step 1

```
d = (3 + 2 > 7) || 7 > 2 ? a-- : a++;
```

Step 2

```
d = false || true ? a-- : a++;
```

Step 3

```
d = true ? a-- : a++;
```

Here value of 'a' will be changed but not in this statement so value of 'a' still be 7
But if you print a in other statement it will changed as 6.

To learn more about operator precedence https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence